# Lex and Yacc defined this syntax give an error

Tags: token, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

```
%union{
    int ival;
    int *ivals;
    char id[20];
    char *str;
}
%start START

%token COMMENT OP_PLUS OP_MINUS OP_DIV OP_MULT OP_OP OP_CP OP_DBLMULT OP_OC OP_CC OP_COMMA KW_AND KW_OR KW_NOT KW_EQUAL KW_LESS
KW_NIL KW_LIST KW_APPEND KW_CONCAT KW_SET KW_DEFFUN KW_FOR KW_IF KW_EXIT KW_DEFVAR KW_WHILE
KW_LOAD KW_DISP KW_TRUE KW_FALSE NEWLINE
FLOAT_NUMBER LISTOP


%token <ival> LIMITED_VALUE
%token <id> IDENTIFIER
%token <str> FLE
%token <ival> NUMBER

%type <ival> START
%type <ival> EXPI
%type <ival> EXPB
%type <ivals> VALUES
%type <ivals> EXPLISTI
%type <ivals> LISTVALUE
%type <ival> BinaryValue

/* Rule Section */
%%     

START:| INPUT{
            if(!flag && list_flag){
                printf("Syntax OK.\n");
                printf("Result:"); 
                
                printList(listValues,listIndex); 
                listIndex=0;
                
                holdIndex=0;
                list_flag=0;
            }
            else if(!flag && binary_flag){
                printf("Syntax OK.\n");
                if($$==1)
                    printf("Result:T\n");
                else
                    printf("Result:NIL\n");
                binary_flag=0;
            }
            else if(!flag){
                printf("Syntax OK.\n");
                printf("Result:%d",$$); 
            }
            return 0;
            };
    
    INPUT: EXPI | EXPLISTI | EXPB{ binary_flag=1; }
    ;
    
    EXPI: OP_OP KW_DEFVAR IDENTIFIER EXPI OP_CP { $$=$4; } 
    | OP_OP KW_SET IDENTIFIER EXPI OP_CP { $$=$4; } 
    | OP_OP OP_PLUS EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3+$4; } 
    | OP_OP OP_MINUS EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3-$4; } 
    | OP_OP OP_MULT EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3*$4; }
    | OP_OP OP_DIV EXPI EXPI OP_CP { $$=$3/$4; }
```

This is in my .y code. If I wrote the (* 5 2) in consol I'm getting error which is SYNTAX_ERROR Expression not recognized.
I have defined this syntax why am I getting such an error? Also, I got errors other defined syntaxes such as (+ 5 2), (/ 5 5)...  What is the reason for such an error?

--Update--
in .l code:

```
%{ 
    #include<stdio.h> 
    #include<math.h>
    #include "y.tab.h" 
    extern YYSTYPE yylval;

    int c_count = 0; // for open " and close "
%}
COMMENT ";;".*
LIMITED_VALUE [0-9]|[1-9][0-9]*
IDENTIFIER [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
FLE ["](.*?)["]

and         "and"
or          "or"
not         "not"
equal       "equal"
less        "less"
nil         "nil"
list        "list"
append      "append"
concat      "concat"
set         "set"
deffun      "deffun"
deffvar     "defvar"
for         "for"
while       "while"
if          "if"
exit        "exit"
load        "load"
disp        "disp"
true        "true"
false       "false"


%%

{COMMENT} { return COMMENT; }
and { return KW_AND; }
or { return KW_OR; }
not { return KW_NOT; }
equal { return KW_EQUAL; }
less { return KW_LESS; }
nil { return KW_NIL; }
list { return KW_LIST; }
append { return KW_APPEND; }
concat { return KW_CONCAT; }
set { return KW_SET; }
deffun { return KW_DEFFUN; }
defvar { return KW_DEFVAR; }
for { return KW_FOR; }
while { return KW_WHILE; }
if { return KW_IF; }
exit { return KW_EXIT; }
load { return KW_LOAD; }
disp { return KW_DISP; }
true { return KW_TRUE; }
false { return KW_FALSE; }
"'(" { return LISTOP; }
"+" { return OP_PLUS; }
"-" { return OP_MINUS; }
"/" { return OP_DIV; }
"*" { return OP_MULT; }
"(" { return OP_OP; }
")" { return OP_CP;}
"**" { return OP_DBLMULT; }
"\"" {if(!c_count%2)
        return OP_OC;
    else
        return OP_CC;
    ++c_count;}
"," { return OP_COMMA; }



[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*   {strcpy(yylval.id, yytext); return IDENTIFIER;}
[[1-9][:digit:]]+         {yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return LIMITED_VALUE;}
{LIMITED_VALUE}                   { yylval.ival = atoi(yytext); return LIMITED_VALUE;}

" "|"\t" { } 
"\n" {printf("%s\n",yytext); return 0; }
.    {printf("SYNTAX ERROR %s IS NOT RECOGNIZED",yytext); return 0;} 
%%

int yywrap() 
{ 
return 1; 
}
```

all my code in this .l is like this.

```
When I try to debug:
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: >(* 5 2)
Next token is token OP_OP ()
Shifting token OP_OP ()
Entering state 2
Reading a token: Next token is token OP_MULT ()
Shifting token OP_MULT ()
Entering state 19
Reading a token: Next token is token LIMITED_VALUE ()

SYNTAX_ERROR Expression not recognized
Error: popping token OP_MULT ()
Stack now 0 2
Error: popping token OP_OP ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token LIMITED_VALUE ()
Stack now 0
```

Comment: @anonim1980: I think you should make some attempt to learn how to debug bison/flex projects, rather than depending on other people, particularly if you are not going to provide your entire project. (The problem(s) are most likely in the parts of your code which you don't provide.) By the way, who suggested that it's a good idea to write YOUR ENTIRE GRAMMAR IN UPPER CASE? It's distracting and hard to read. The usual convention is that only tokens (terminals) are written in CAPS and the rest of the grammar is written in eye-friendly lower case.

Comment: See [the bison manual chapter on Debugging Your Parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging) for a good introduction to techniques for debugging your parser.

Comment: @rici I update code in my question

Comment: Nothing in the code you pasted defines `EXPB` or `EXPLISTI`, which means that either there's more to the grammar or you haven't mentioned the errors Bison produces. If that is your complete code, I don't see any production which uses `LIMITED_VALUE`, so naturally `5` would cause a syntax error. Also you didn't answer my question. Trying to read your code gives me a headache. Do you have a professor who insists on that bizarre style?

Comment: @rici   yes, my professor asked for it that way.

Comment: @rici entire code of my .y file: https://   paste.ofcode.org/fXXp27zuWZstSjFcnEManq

Comment: That url doesn't work for me, even when I remove the space. But anyway, this isn't a "debug my homework" site. You need to take some responsibility. Learning how to debug is 75% of the task of learning to be a programmer, although I don't suppose you'll learn that in a CS curriculum. Read the Bison manual section on debugging and make an effort; then try to ask a more focussed question than "please make my mistakes vanish." (Hint: cuttiing down your program to an [mre] is not just a SO requirement. It's a very effective debugging technique.) Good luck.

Comment: I try debug my code but I could not figure out. thank you for answer

Comment: @rici I edit my question with debug result

Comment: Several hours ago, I wrote " If that is your complete code, I don't see any production which uses LIMITED_VALUE, so naturally 5 would cause a syntax error. " Was I wrong? Did you try to fix that? Don't you see in that trace that the parser jammed when it read the `5`? Thoughts?

Comment: I get that you struggle with English. That's a pain, but you have a lot more resources available to you than I did when I had to learn the languages of the countries I've lived in. Machine translation is far from perfect but it helps a lot. So does working with a friend who maybe understands some of it. Bottom line: if you can't ask good questions or understand responses, you need to work even harder on your debugging skills.